# Do i need Hyper-V to debug my android app from within Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, windows-7-x64, hyper-v

I an having trouble debugging my native Android app. My Visual Studio 2015 (preview) installation does not show any emulator in the dropdown list.

I saw one comment here saying that Hyper-V must be enabled. Is that true?  If yes, how to enable Hyper-V on my Windows 7 x64 machine? Is it possible to install Hyper-V on Windows 7 x64?

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows 7 machine should already have Hyper-V on it. You may need to reboot, get into the BIOS settings and look for a switch that enables Hyper-V. A lot of manufacturers disable it by default.

Once you've done so, take a look at http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html for more instructions on downloading and running emulators.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [new Android emulator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx) written by Microsoft included with Visual Studio 2015 and it requires Hyper-V. [Hyper-V is not available for use on a Windows 7 guest OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V#System_requirements). You will have to upgrade to Windows 8 Pro (you'd probably choose 8.1) to use the new emulator.

It might still be possible to use the "old" Google-provided emulator with VS 2015 but I haven't found information about that.